# Refer to the current instance inside Object.defineProperty(#value)

Tags: javascript, prototype, defineproperty

I am trying to make the method `getColor()` non-configurable, but when I tried to refer to the current instance property of the Fruit "class" using `this.color` it did't work. Seems like `this` doesn't refer to the `Fruit`instance. How can I refer to the instance?

> The function body defined for the property isn't a mutator, here its just an example

```
Object.defineProperty(Fruit.prototype, 'getColor', {
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function(){
        return this.color;  // this refers to Object here
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you setting the color on the instance of Fruit, or do you have `this.color` defined inside the Fruit constructor function ? In either way `this.color` should refer to the instance of Fruit. What exactly do you mean by *it didn't work* ?

Comment: I want to refer to the color variable of the Fruit's instance